# Can a Mercurial subrepostiory reside in a subfolder?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-subrepos, subrepos

I used the have the following line in my `.hgsub` for years:

```
setup/help = https://my.repo.com/manuals
```

It would place the repository named "manuals" into a folder `help` inside another folder `setup`. So my parent repository structure looks like this:

```
.hg
setup
|__help
|  |__.hg
|
.hgsub
```

This was no problem until I updated to Mercurial 4.9 today, it now says: "subrepo path contains illegal component: setup/help", and I can't even commit to the main repo. Does Mercurial forbid this now? Is there a valid `.hgsub` syntax to make this work? I don't want to move `help` to be a direct child of the main project folder. My previous Mercurial version was 4.5, it's not like I was using ancient tools...

Error traceback as per the request:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mercurial\scmutil.pyo", line 165, in callcatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 367, in _runcatchfunc
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 1021, in _dispatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 756, in runcommand
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 1030, in _runcommand
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 1018, in <lambda>
  File "mercurial\util.pyo", line 1670, in check
  File "mercurial\commands.pyo", line 4621, in push
  File "mercurial\context.pyo", line 277, in sub
  File "mercurial\subrepo.pyo", line 164, in subrepo
  File "mercurial\subrepo.pyo", line 414, in __init__
Abort: subrepo path contains illegal component: setup/help
abort: subrepo path contains illegal component: setup/help
```

Comment: It should not be a problem. Could you share a bit more information about your current setup and on-disk status? Is `setup/help` subrepo already cloned? Is there any unusual thing about your setup? Like `setup` or `setup/help` being a symlink?

Comment: @BorisFeld: I already had a local copy of the main repo including all the subrepos, and simply updating Mercurial brought the error messages. Rolled back to 4.6 and no problem with that version.
Windows, no symlinks, nothing unusual at all that I can think about.

Comment: Could you try running whatever hg command you ran when you were getting the message "subrepo path contains illegal component: setup/help" and add the ``--traceback` flag so we can get the full traceback?

Comment: @BorisFeld: added it to the question body.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same error, so I cloned the mercurial repository...

The error was introduced in tagged version 4.9, subrepo.py.

It was corrected about a month later, revision 41583 (87a6e3c953e045d92147925fc71aad7c327fdbfd).
I tested it on the actual default branch, works again!

So, no need for a bug entry, we just have to wait for the next release.

Comment: Thank you!
Pity that things like this make it into releases, but oh well, we've all been there a couple times, I'm sure.

Comment: The release 4.9.1 has been released just now on Pypi.

Answer (score 1):

How confident are you with a Python debugger? You can launch the command with the `--debugger` this time.

You might see an output like this:

```
entering debugger - type c to continue starting hg or h for help
--Call--
> /usr/lib64/python2.7/contextlib.py(21)__exit__()
-> def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
(Pdb)
```

Enter `c` and `enter` until you see the same traceback as the one you pasted.

When you are at the right traceback, you can print the local variables using `pp root`, `pp util.expandpath(root)` and `os.path.realpath(util.expandpath(root))`. We should be able to get to the root of the issue with the values of those variables.

To exit the debugger, enter `q` and `enter`.